# Show that $\frac 1x \ge 3 - 2\sqrt{x}$ for all positive real numbers $x$. Describe when we have equality.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Show that $\frac 1x \ge 3 - 2\sqrt{x}$ for all positive real numbers $x$. Describe when we have equality.

I tried manipulating the equation but nothing helps.  Any answer is greatly appreciated.

Comment: One simple method is using A-G mean inequality

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$
\frac{1}{x} \geq 3 - 2\sqrt{x} \iff \frac{1+2x\sqrt{x} -3x}{x} \geq 0 \iff \frac{(\sqrt{x}-1)^2(\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2})}{x} \geq 0
$$
We can cancel off the $(\sqrt{x}-1)^2$, and the $x$ on the bottom, since $x$ must be positive, and squares are always positive. This leaves us with $\sqrt{x} + \frac{1}{2} \geq 0$, which is true for all positive $x$. Hence this inequality also applies for all positive $x$.

Equality will apply when $x=1$, since $\sqrt{x}+\frac{1}{2}$ is strictly positive, and $\frac{1}x$ is strictly positive for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Good observation.

Comment: @martycohen Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Set $t=\sqrt x$. It amounts to showing that 
$$\frac1{t^2}\ge3-2t\iff 1\ge 3t^2-2t^3$$
Now if $f(t)=3t^2-2t^3$, $f'(t)=6t(1-t)$, so on $[0,+\infty)$, attains a maximum at $t=1$, and precisely $g(1)=1$.

Comment: +1: Need idea to use a bijection on the required domain for a nicer form of the function.

Comment: It's a common idea to simplify using a rational parametrisation.

Comment: It's new to me in any case, so I think it's a useful answer apart from just solving the immediate problem.